# How do I get Seaborn Barplot bars' colors darker as they become greater/smaller?

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart, visualization

I am plotting a list of daily, weekly, monthly IPO stocks performance. I want the bars' colors to grow darker as they get greater/smaller.

```
palletes that I use:

color_daily = ['red' if x < 0 else 'green' for x in ipo_stocks.sort_values('Daily Return (%)')['Daily Return (%)']]
color_weekly = ['red' if x < 0 else 'green' for x in ipo_stocks.sort_values('Weekly Return (%)')['Weekly Return (%)']]
color_monthly = ['red' if x < 0 else 'green' for x in ipo_stocks.sort_values('Monthly Return (%)')['Monthly Return (%)']]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize = (15,15))

fig_1 = sns.barplot(data = ipo_stocks.sort_values('Daily Return (%)'), x = 'Saham', y = 'Daily Return (%)', palette = color_daily, alpha = 0.8, ax = axes[0])
fig_1.set(ylim = (-50,50))
axes[0].tick_params(labelrotation = 90)
axes[0].text(2,40, ('Rata-rata return hari pertama listing: ' + str(round(ipo_stocks['Daily Return (%)'].mean(), 2)) + '%'), fontsize = 15)
axes[0].title.set_text('Performa Daily')

fig_2 = sns.barplot(data = ipo_stocks.sort_values('Weekly Return (%)'), x = 'Saham', y = 'Weekly Return (%)', palette = color_weekly, alpha = 0.8, ax = axes[1])
fig_2.set(ylim = (-100, 300))
axes[1].tick_params(labelrotation = 90)
axes[1].text(2, 250, ('Rata-rata return satu minggu setelah listing: ' + str(round(ipo_stocks['Weekly Return (%)'].mean(), 2)) + '%'), fontsize = 15)
axes[1].title.set_text('Performa Weekly')

fig_3 = sns.barplot(data = ipo_stocks.sort_values('Monthly Return (%)'), x = 'Saham', y = 'Monthly Return (%)', palette = color_monthly, alpha = 0.8, ax = axes[2])
fig_3.set(ylim = (-100, 400))
axes[2].tick_params(labelrotation = 90)
axes[2].text(2, 300, ('Rata-rata return satu bulan setelah listing: ' + str(round(ipo_stocks['Monthly Return (%)'].mean(), 2)) + '%'), fontsize = 15)
axes[2].title.set_text('Performa Monthly')

plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Output image:]

Comment: Note that I updated the rescaling function to ensure having white at zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom colormap and rescaling your values:

```
from  matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

N = 20
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.linspace(-2, 5, N),
                   'x': range(N),
                  })

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('red_green', ['r', 'w', 'g']) 

def rescale(s):
    return s/s.max()/2 + 0.5

sns.barplot(data=df, x='x', y='value', palette=cmap(rescale(df['value'])))
```

*NB. note that shifting from red to green is not colorblind-friendly.*

Output:

[image: barplot custom palette gradient]